# Is there an option for modeling application and generate code accordingly In JetBrains products?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I will explain my self to details.

If I want to build an application by modeling by a complicated big diagrams with structure and relations, like this picture:
(Classes, functions, and so on...)

[image]

Is there exist a JetBrains product for It?

Is there option for generate automatically code In python accordingly?

Is there option for by selecting web framework like Django or Flask and given a model diagram and to generate automatically advance code accordingly to this framework prerequisite?

Maybe all this futuristic, but I think It can be very helpful to be productive.

Comment: PyCharm professional has this feature integrated, see [Working with diagrams](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-diagrams.html) Otherwise there are a coutless number of 3rd party tools for the job see [google](https://www.google.com/search?&q=generate+python+code+from+UML)

Comment: There is no such a feature in PyCharm or IntelliJ IDEA at the moment.